# How does Google detects automated queries

Tags: c#, performance, security, web

i am currently developing a web application which  will be flown up with queries daily ,to ensure security i wish to protect the users with automated queries,

If we look over at Google ,It detects automated queries and bans the ip address and results like this

[image]

Can anyone explain the program analogy implied for detecting automated queries?how does they do this? is it Possible to achieve the similar stuff in my web application,is it network based or they have implied some programming stuff detect automated queries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely the _frequency_ of your queries. I.e. how often you send a query from a specific IP address within a certain timespan.

Comment: @UweKeim but it occurs with dynamic ip's too, for e.g while using tor with anonymity

Comment: Maybe in addition cookies or something similar? (e.g. calculating a Hash from the User Agent).

Answer (score 0):

Google shows that error when client or one computer from same internal network with client-because they share same NAT ip address- has been infected by malware.

As Uwe Keim said, google is tracing frequency of queries. You can check out "how many request came from each client for last 1 minute ?" it should be around N. You can make a decision about limit of number B for your application.